# Hlookup with variable input

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make VBA, which find out throught "LOOP" the correct row (i + 1) and after that via using "Hlookup function" find out the correct value from "This row". Finding value is for expample "99". I have problem with "hlookup function.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable1()
Dim maxfromROW As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook


i = 1

Do Until Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = "This row"

i = i + 1
Loop

maxfromROW = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(99, Range("A4:O20"), i + 1, False)

wb.Worksheets("Hárok1").Range("B20").Value = maxOVB2
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with the `hlookup` function exactly. E.g., what are you trying to do and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons why your code should not be working:

1. You are not having `Option Explicit` and you are not declaring variables
2. You go into endless while loop.
3. You do not have a value for the HLookup and you are using `.WorksheetFunction`, which returns automatically run-time error, if no value is found.

Instead of `Application.WorksheetFunciton()`, try `Application.HLookup`, which would not throw a run-time error but a simple error, if no value is found:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim someResult As Variant
    someResult = Application.HLookup(99, Worksheets(1).Range("A4:O20"), 3, False)

    If Not IsError(someResult) Then
        Debug.Print someResult
    Else
        Debug.Print someResult; " is an error!"
    End If

End Sub
```